# Is there a verb specifically meaning 'to mock something one does not understand?'

Tags: single-word-requests

In the film Idiocracy, Joe Bowers is often mocked or ridiculed as being the unintelligent one simply because the others around him lack the wherewithal to properly understand him. I am familiar with words like jeer, deride, scoff, etc. but is there any verb (or any other word form) that specifically pertains, or is limited to, ridicule stemming from one's own lack of knowledge or understanding?

Comment: Malign comes to mind

Answer (score 2):

One could characterize those who mock Joe Bowers as *prejudiced* or *close-minded*. Their *prejudice* or *close-mindedness* is the root cause of their mocking, and in the case of *prejudice*, its manifestation in "an irrational attitude of hostility".

M-W:

> [*prejudice*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prejudice):
>   preconceived judgment or opinion; an adverse opinion or leaning formed
>   without just grounds or before sufficient knowledge / *an irrational
>   attitude of hostility* directed against an individual, a group, a
>   race, or their supposed characteristics [emphasis added]
>
> [*close-minded*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/close-minded):
>   not willing to consider different ideas or opinions :  having or
>   showing a closed mind

Answer (score 1):

It's curious that there isn't an obvious word for this, as it's a specific and common thing. "Sneering" (or "jeering") is pretty close, as it has a connotation of being base or unthinking.

To "discount" or "dismiss" someone suggests that your opinion is not based on trying to understand them; but those terms don't necessarily imply mockery.

I think the problem is, the meanings of verbs tend to be framed around the subject's point of view, and people don't view their own thoughts as ignorant--they view them as correct, and it's for *others* to point out the ignorance. If I say "Steve foolishly scorned my theories about fluoride", it's clear that the verb represents Steve's position, and the adverb represents my take on it.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly ***burlesque***, defined by the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/25000?rskey=P7kS8j&result=2#eid) as:

> v trans. To turn into ridicule by grotesque parody or imitation; to
>   caricature, travesty

***caricature*** [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/27974?rskey=rJMcxC&result=2#eid)

> v trans. To represent or portray in caricature; to make a grotesque
>   likeness of

***travesty***, [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/205301?rskey=erI5r6&result=2#eid)

> v trans. To turn into ridicule by grotesque parody or imitation; to
>   caricature, burlesque

The trouble with these words as an answer to the OP's question, is that if burlesque or caricature or travesty is cleverly done, they can bring out truths about a person.  However, frequently they are done in malicious ignorance, for example (made up):

> The schoolchildren took delight in caricaturing the strong accent and
>   the limp of the elderly professor.

Thus, depending on the context, these words can meet the OP's requirement of:

> specifically pertains....to, ridicule stemming from one's
>   own lack of knowledge or understanding